# Cross compile with cmake for arm with static linked boost library

Tags: c++, linux, boost, cmake, cross-compiling

what I have:

- a c++ project which uses the boost library
- the project is build with cmake and links boost dynamically
- a linux machine with x64
- a dev board with an arm processor and linux

what I want:

One CMake project which does the follows:

- one build for the x64 architecture (for gtest and local development)
- another build for the arm architecture
- **both with static linked boost library**

Is this possible, and if so, how?

IMHO the main issue is to tell cmake, that for the second build it should use another (this time for arm) precompiled boost library to link. No idea how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Assumed that you use `find_package(Boost ..)` to search and select boost components (as you should) and if I get your question right you can just build in two different directories (as you most likely do already) and set CMake Variable **BOOST_ROOT** differently *before*  configuring.

You can also just set **Boost_LIBRARIES** later in case the rest is equal.

To tell CMake to link Boost statically just set **Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS** to **ON**.